# any one help grid view unable to show the data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

any help me

i want below summary for gridview sql data as for the below

SQL DATA

SQL DATA :

```
Date        Week        GO_HQ   LPSC_TGT    LPSC_ACH
29-Apr-17   Week - 18   ADAYAR  4.25        3.42
30-Apr-17   Week - 18   ADAYAR  4.25        0
1-May-17    Week - 18   ADAYAR  4.25        0
2-May-17    Week - 18   ADAYAR  4.25        3.5
3-May-17    Week - 18   ADAYAR  4.25        3.1
4-May-17    Week - 18   ADAYAR  4.25        3.19
5-May-17    Week - 18   ADAYAR  4.25        0
6-May-17    Week - 19   ADAYAR  4.25        3.13
7-May-17    Week - 19   ADAYAR  4.25        2.2
8-May-17    Week - 19   ADAYAR  4.25        3.5
9-May-17    Week - 19   ADAYAR  4.25        4.2
10-May-17   Week - 19   ADAYAR  4.25        0
11-May-17   Week - 19   ADAYAR  4.25        0
12-May-17   Week - 19   ADAYAR  4.25        0
13-May-17   Week - 20   ADAYAR  4.25        0
14-May-17   Week - 20   ADAYAR  4.25        0
15-May-17   Week - 20   ADAYAR  4.25        0
16-May-17   Week - 20   ADAYAR  4.25        0
17-May-17   Week - 20   ADAYAR  4.25        0
18-May-17   Week - 20   ADAYAR  4.25        0
19-May-17   Week - 20   ADAYAR  4.25        0
20-May-17   Week - 21   ADAYAR  4.25        0
21-May-17   Week - 21   ADAYAR  4.25        0
22-May-17   Week - 21   ADAYAR  4.25        0
23-May-17   Week - 21   ADAYAR  4.25        0
24-May-17   Week - 21   ADAYAR  4.25        0
25-May-17   Week - 21   ADAYAR  4.25        0
26-May-17   Week - 21   ADAYAR  4.25        0
27-May-17   Week - 22   ADAYAR  4.25        0
28-May-17   Week - 22   ADAYAR  4.25        0
29-May-17   Week - 22   ADAYAR  4.25        0
30-May-17   Week - 22   ADAYAR  4.25        0
31-May-17   Week - 22   ADAYAR  4.25        0
1-Jun-17    Week - 22   ADAYAR  4.25        0
2-Jun-17    Week - 22   ADAYAR  4.25        0
```

i want summary below

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please take a minute to read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and maybe [Writing the perfect question.](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and try writing a better question, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can do simple pivot for getting this as below:

```
select * from (
   select Week, Go_hq, LPSC_ACH from yourtable ) a
      pivot (sum(LPSC_ACH) for week in ([Week - 18]...)) p
```

For dynamic weeks:

```
declare  @cols3  nvarchar(max)
declare  @Query  nvarchar(max)

select @cols3 = stuff((select ','+ QUOTENAME([week]) from #yourdates group by [week] order by [week] for xml path(N''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,N'')

select @cols3
SELECT @Query = 'select * from (
   select [Week], Go_hq, LPSC_ACH from #yourdates ) a
      pivot (sum(LPSC_ACH) for [Week] in ('+ @cols3 +')) p '

exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: very thanks sir but week column is not static , its dynamically  changing 4 or 5 ,6 weeks how to fixed that

Comment: you can use dynamic sql for that

Comment: sir need your intro

Comment: Updated my answer... are you looking that?

Comment: This solution works? or you are looking for including date as well?